# Spaces in URIs in Firefox 7

Tags: javascript, firefox, uri, url-encoding

In Firefox version 7.0.1, URIs with encoded spaces in them are automatically converted to a space in the Location Bar.

This does not happen in Internet Explorer.

For example, I have a textbox on a page with contents of "Test Test".  I have a javascript function that reloads the page with the encoded contents of the textbox using encodeURIComponent().

Internet Explorer produces:

```
http://host/page.php?box=Test%20Test
```

Firefox 7.0.1 produces:

```
http://host/page.php?box=Test Test
```

Upon alerting out the results of encodeURIComponent in Firefox, the space is correctly escaped as %20.

It appears Firefox is doing something that is removing the encoding from the URI.  This then results in the URI not conforming to [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

My question is what should I as a developer do?  In fact, do I need to do anything?

Comment: What's important isn't what's in the location bar, but what the actual *request* looks like. My bet is Firefox properly URL encodes it before sending it

Comment: @Pekka, yes it appears you are right.  See my comment in reply to Holger below.

Comment: "Firefox 7.0.1 produces:" `host/page.php?box=Test Test`. Then you can really see that it's not meant to be a valid URL.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Well to be fair, I took out the S of my https, which is actually appearing in the location bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This applies only to the URL field that Firefox shows to the user, not the actual request that gets made.

If you look at the request in Firefox 7 on Windows 7, you will see that the spaces get URL encoded:

[image]

Comment: Good call.  Confirmed that the %20 is actually being sent

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just Firefox way of showing the URL.

I've also noticed it removed http:// from the URL, but when you copy the URL and paste it in IE or Notepad the http:// is there.

So I don't think you need to do anything, it's just Firefox trying to make the URL easier to read.

Comment: You're right!  I never noticed the lack of http in the location bar.  I copied and pasted the url that has the space in it, and yes, in notepad it has the %20.  So, it appears I don't have to do anything at all.  Your answer was good and before Pekka's, but I'm going to accept Pekka's because he actually showed proof of what was happening.

Comment: You're wrong about `&amp;`; that's the HTML encoding. What any browser will interpret is a literal ampersand. The `amp;` is never part of the URL.

Comment: Ah you're right, I just remembered it as it also converted the `&amp;` to `&`. I'll remove it from my answer.